# PI Vision Extensibility

Tags: osisoft

I want to develop a PI Vision extensibility custom symbol, on click the button loops through all the link buttons in the display, retrieves the link paths and sets them to the specific text and rectangle symbols in the display.

I have developed PI Vision Extensibility custom symbols before, but im having trouble finding any documentation since OSI Soft deleted their github repo, and their documentation is limited to specific functionalities.